# Variable in Jinja2 For Loop

Tags: ansible, jinja2

We're trying to come up with a way to use ansible facts within jinja2 For Loops.

For example, I want to get all servers that belong to my memcached group as well as a group based on release (something like `tag_release_dev` or `tag_release_prod`).  When I try to use `{{ tt_release }}` within the For Loop it evaluates `{{ tt_release }}` rather than the value of the variable.  Is there a way to use a variable within the loop definition?

```
{% for host in groups["tag_function_mem"] | intersect(groups["tag_release_{{ tt_release }}"]) %}
  {{ host }}:11211
  {%- if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
  {%- if loop.last %}"{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it evaluates `{{ tt_release }}` rather than the value of the variable.

This is because you already are inside a expression. You can not nest expressions - and you don't need to.

What you want is to concatenate the string `"tag_release_"` and the variable `tt_release`. In Jinja2 concatenation is done with a `+`.

```
{% for host in groups["tag_function_mem"] | intersect(groups["tag_release_" + tt_release]) %}
```