# dereference a jinja2 string into a var?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have something like this:

```
item = bar
foobar = { a: b, b: c }
```

and then in the jinja template:

```
{{'foo' ~ item}}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get a *key* of foobar, but that simply returns the string `foobar`.

I've tried a few things:

```
{{('foo' ~ item).a}}
{{'foo' ~ item.a}}
{{{{'foo' ~ item}}.a}}
```

Ultimately, they are coming out as the string `foobar`, not evaluating the variable `foobar` .. except the last one, which simply breaks. [I'd know how to reference it if it was a dict key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212827/659298) .. but I don't know how to do it like this.

(specifically, this is coming from combining a string with an `{{item}}` in Ansible. So the answer isn't "use `{{foobar.a}}`".)

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/40968307/2795592

Comment: @techraf good idea. my twitter name is the same, btw, if you want to contact me that way. (heh, we'll see if anyone flags this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following script:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  vars:
    - itemn: bar
    - foobar: {"a":"b", "b":"c"}

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{vars['foo' ~ itemn]['a']}}"
```